# How do I run a parallel for loop to read with specified amount of threads?

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops

I currently have this for loop that reads each line in a textfile and runs a boolean function 'IsValid':

```
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\file.txt")
        Console.WriteLine("Working On: " & line)
        Console.WriteLine(IsValid(line))
    Next
```

How do I go about making this process parallel with specified amount of 'threads'?

**Edit:**

I tried adding: "AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)", but it is still doing one iteration at a time.

```
For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\file.txt").AsParallel().WithDegreeOfParallelism(5)
```

Comment: I suggest you learn more about concurrent programming.

Comment: How in the world would you keep your data straight with multiple threads entering your For? Threads run according to the thread scheduler and can be stopped and started at inconvenient times (beyond your control).

Comment: I recommend reading Stephen Toub's *Patterns of Parallel Programming* which explains how to use parallel programming in VB.Net. You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222

Answer (score 1):

A `For Each` loop is a `For Each` loop. If you want parallel programming then you can use an actual `For Each` loop because it is inherently not parallel.  The `AsParallel` method you're calling returns a `ParallelEnumerable` so you can only call PLINQ methods on that. To achieve your aim, you might use:

```
File.ReadLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\file.txt").
     AsParallel().
     WithDegreeOfParallelism(5).
     ForAll(Sub(line)
                Console.WriteLine("Working On: " & line)
                Console.WriteLine(IsValid(line))
            End Sub)
```

The alternative would be to call `Parallel.ForEach`. You'd need to call one of the overloads that takes a `ParallelOptions` object as an argument and you can specify the `MaxDegreesOfParallelism` property:

```
Parallel.ForEach(File.ReadLines(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\file.txt"),
                 New ParallelOptions With {.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5},
                 Sub(line)
                     Console.WriteLine("Working On: " & line)
                     Console.WriteLine(IsValid(line))
                 End Sub)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I knew basically nothing about that `AsParallel` method prior to reading your question and simply read the documentation for it. I've also never used the `ParallelOptions` class and just read about it in the documentation for `Parallel.ForEach`. That said, I did that reading in the context of someone with far more experience with .NET, LINQ and the MSDN documentation than you, but I've been reading that documentation since I was a beginner teaching myself, so you should too. Other than that, I have no specific resources to recommend on the subject.

Comment: By the way, do please accept an answer if it solves your issue. That way, everyone can see that the issue is resolved without opening the thread.